# google-play-services_lib.jar missing after updating to latest version (3.1)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've been using Google play services in my app for a while with no prob. I'm using Eclipse. I've updated play services(and ADT and SDK) to the latest version after I/O and now I can not get my app to build.  I have added the google-play-services_lib project to my app as a library project.  However when I go to the java build path for my project I get a red X next to google-play-services_lib under android dependencies.  It is looking in the /bin/ dir for google-play-services_lib.jar, however it is never build.  Anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Try going to Project -> Properties -> Order & Export and ensure Android Private Libraries are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using.

Comment: It is checked in all projects.

Comment: goto your android sdk manager check if Andorid Build Tools is installed. if you have red x meaning its a broken link for the library project

Comment: I found this just now...I did not have the new build tools installed.  This fixed the problem and the jar file is now generated.  Answer the question and I will accept it.

Comment: @Patick sure i just posted the comment as an answer for clarity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Converting comment to answer

After updating Android SDK and ADT make sure you have Android Build tools installed.

Goto your android sdk manager check if Andorid Build Tools is installed. If not installed install the same.

Comment: it's amazing. i updated everything in the SDK manager and then updated things within eclipse... who would have thought that I actually need to go back in to the SDK manager to update YET AGAIN. a bit cyclical and unintuitive, but thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I did this step but Google Play Services lib still missing for me

Comment: @fuzzybee i don't know what you have done in your situation. pls post a new question

Comment: i had two entries for google android build tools - one was v17, the other was v18.x. I had to manually check the box for v18.x, but after installing it, all was well.

Comment: This fixed it for me, but only when I replaced Build Tools 18.0.1 with 18.1 (this update wasn't performed automatically)

Answer (score 3):

So simple, I don't know how I missed it. Right click on the project library and select *build project*. I forgot I had turned *project* > *build automatically* off.